# What is the correct pattern in React JS to invoke a component method on specific props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, lifecycle

Using React and Redux, imagine you have a component method that sends a request to an external API.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComp extends Component {

  boolUpdate (val) {
    fetch('http://myapi.com/bool', { val });
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
    return false;
  }

  render () {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>;
  }

}

const mapStateToProps = ({ bool }) => ({ bool });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComp);
```

Now let's say that you want to invoke `boolUpdate()` each time the `bool` prop changes, but this should not trigger a component update because nothing in the render of the component is affected.

What's the best way to do this in React?

Until recently people used to do something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.bool !== this.props.bool) this.boolUpdate(nextProps.bool);
}
```

But as of React v16.3 `componentWillReceiveProps()` has been deprecated. In this example we can't use `componentDidUpdate()` either, because `shouldComponentUpdate()` prevents that from happening. And `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is a static method, so it doesn't have access to the instance methods.

So, the only option we're left with seems to be using `shouldComponentUpdate()` itself. Something along the lines of:

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.bool !== this.props.bool) this.boolUpdate(nextProps.bool);
  return false;
}
```

This looks rather "hacky" to me though, and not what `shouldComponentUpdate()` was designed for.

Does anybody have a better pattern to suggest?

Is there a preferred way to listen to specific prop changes and trigger component methods?

Thanks!

Comment: Off-topic. The situation that you have some boolean flag in redux store but calling external API from within the component's method is very suspicious. :)

Comment: What if you handled this outside of the component and in the reducer instead. Each time you update the value of `bool` in state you also make your API call?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore this could be handled in a Redux middleware indeed. I just wonder if there's a good pattern to handle it directly in the component though.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want it handled in the component? As @YuryTarabanko mentions above, it's a code smell

Comment: The new react suspense pattern will make async call inside render :). So, no idea what the best place is. One way to do it can be to store the old value in an instance property and compare against that in componentDidUpdate

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I have a feeling that moving component logic to middleware just because it's async sometimes makes it harder in a complex app to keep track of where things are happening. I would love if there was an elegant solution to keep this logic inside the component itself.

Comment: @MukeshSoni yep that's a pattern that React after v16.3 seems to be leaning towards, although it doesn't work if you avoid re-rendering by returning `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate()` because then `componentDidUpdate()` is never invoked. And in this case for example re-rendering is not necessary, so it would be better to be able to avoid it.

Comment: @Pensierinmusica in my experience, the separation of concerns actually helps in a complex app. The redux middleware contains all your actions and logic, and the components just concentrate on building the DOM

Comment: @ChristopherMoore possible, although in my case the async logic would be dependent of where the user is in the UI in that moment. So, not entirely sure. I could track the current route and use conditionals, but it seems more elegant to keep it in the component itself. Again, not sure. Also RxJS and Redux Observable seem interesting options: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable

Comment: @Pensierinmusica I think your solution with `shouldComponentUpdate` is actually the least hacky and your cleanest, logical place to do this. Next to doing it where the changed prop comes from obviously, which would be an action I assume. So why not let that action do the request? Your cornering yourself with the "in the component" constraint. It feels hacky because it's a very unusual scenario beyond the scope of a view rendering library. The props are changed by redux, and the api call is made with something that is not react i'm assuming.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run some code (e.g. data fetching) when props change, do it in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

In your example, this won't work because `shouldComponentUpdate` returns `false`. I'd argue this is not a very common case because typically you still want to re-render if props change.

For example, **if the user ID changes, you might want to show a loading indicator while the data for the new user is loading.** So avoiding a re-render is not very useful in this case.

However, if you're absolutely sure you **both** need to prevent a re-render **and** need to perform a side effect like fetching data on props change, you can **split your component in two**. The outer component would do the data fetching in `componentDidUpdate`, and return `<InnerComponent {...this.props} />`. The inner component would have a `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation that prevents re-rendering further. Again, I wouldn't expect this to be a common scenario, but you can do this.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data-when-props-change) and [this](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/721) discussion on github, The place to fetch new data based on props change is actually `componentDidUpdate`.

The rendering was actually splitted to two phases, the `Render Phase` which is pure and creates no side effects and the `Commit Phase` which can run side effects, work with the DOM and schedule updates.

You can see that explained well in Dan Abramov's diagram:
[image]

Dan also mentioned:

> People used to mix these two different things in
>   componentWillReceiveProps, which is why we have to split it into a
>   pure method (getDerivedStateFromProps) and an existing impure one
>   where it’s okay to do side effects (componentDidUpdate).

And for the solution itself, Im attaching the example from the docs:

> **Fetching external data when props change**
>
> Here is an example of a component that fetches external data based on props values:
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>   this._loadAsyncData(this.props.id);
> }
>
> componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
>   if (nextProps.id !== this.props.id) {
>     this.setState({externalData: null});
>     this._loadAsyncData(nextProps.id);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
>   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
>     if (nextProps.id !== prevState.prevId) {
>       return {
>         externalData: null,
>         prevId: nextProps.id,
>       };
>     }
>     return null;
>   }
>
>   componentDidMount() {
>     this._loadAsyncData(this.props.id);
>   }
>
>   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
>     if (this.state.externalData === null) {
>       this._loadAsyncData(this.props.id);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: This answer is meant to be more exhaustive but I think there's a simpler solution in this particular case :-) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49779063/458193

Comment: @DanAbramov, I Totally missed that part got into it too soon. Thanks.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to match the docs more clearly—for example, you added some code to "after" that was already present in the "before" state, which made it a bit confusing. Hope that's okay, and thanks for posting the answer!