# Adding/Removing animation classes with react + redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to display quick flash animations on certain events (eg. a red border flash for each incorrect keystroke).

To do this with css animations, I need to remove and add the animation class each time I want to trigger the flash. (Unless there's another way to retrigger an animation?).

There are a few suggestions for doing this on this github thread: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7142

However, in my case the state that triggers the flash is the redux state. And in many cases the state hasn't actually changed, so it doesn't cause a rerender.

Here's the best solution I've got, which involves setting a random number to force a re-render. Is there a better way to do this?

**reducer.js**

```
//Reducer function to update redux state
function setError(state, action) {    
    state.hasError = true; 
    state.random = Math.random(); 
    return state; 
}


export default function allReducers(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.SUBMIT_VALUE_BUTTON:
      return Object.assign({}, state, setError(state, action));

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**react component and container**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    random: state.random,
    hasError: state.hasError, 
  }
}

componentWillReceiveProps() {
  this.setState({hasError: this.props.hasError});
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({hasError: false});
  }, 300)
}


render() {
    return <div className = {`my-component ${this.state.hasError ? 'has-error':''}`} />; 

}
```

**Edit:** It's worth noting that the redux documentation says that you shouldn't call non-pure functions like Math.random in a reducer method.

> Things you should never do inside a reducer:
>
> Call non-pure functions, e.g. Date.now() or Math.random().

Comment: Redux state should be immutable! You have to understand why you action does not trigger a render call.

Comment: @MotiKorets I might have used the wrong word. Clearly redux state can be updated. The reason it doesn't trigger a render call is because, for example if `state.hasError === false` and I try reset it to false again with `Object.assign` redux won't detect it.

Comment: i"m talking about the code. `setError` clearly mutates state which should never be done. Reducer is a function which receives old state and action and returns new state. In any case the component has inner state so i don't really get it why you need it to be aware of redux at all.

Comment: @MotiKorets That's just the reducer function. I'll add a bit more for clarity.

Comment: I think the complete component code would be helpful. And consider rewrite it without redux as i feel it only gets in your way here.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few problems in it, I'll go one by one...

You can't mutate the state object on the reducer. Here it is from the redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers):

> Note that:
>
> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign().
>   Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter }) is also
>   wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty
>   object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread
>   operator proposal to write { ...state, ...newState } instead.

In your code `setError` receives the state as a prop and mutates it. `setError` should look like this:

```
function setError(state, action) {    
    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
    newState.hasError = true; 
    newState.random = Math.random(); 
    return newState; 
}
```

The second problem might be because there's some code missing but I cant see when your'e changing your state back to no errors so the props doesnt really change.

In your `componentWillReceiveProps` your referencing `this.props` instead of `nextProps`.

`componentWillReceiveProps` should look like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.hasError !== this.props.hasError && nextProps.hasError){
     setTimeout(() => {
      // Dispatch redux action to clear errors
    }, 300)
  }
}
```

And in your component you should check for props and not state as getting props should cause rerender (unless the render is stopped in `componentShouldUpdate`):

```
render() {
    return <div className={`my-component ${this.props.hasError ? 'has-error':''}`} />; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. 

1. I'm not actually manipulating the state directly. Note that there's the object.assign in the allReducers method. 

2. Thanks for pointing that out. It looks like I should be using `getDerivedStateFromProps` anyway. 

3. The point of mentioning state is because it's the random number that causes the rerender, not the hasError property.

Comment: @dwjohnston Actually, in this case I would probably use `componentDidUpdate` since your'e creating side effects for the component(setTimeout). You can have a look at my answer to see when should you put such a logic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772726/what-is-the-correct-pattern-in-react-js-to-invoke-a-component-method-on-specific/49777146#49777146
Regarding your problem, I think that some code is missing to figure it out. Where are you updating your `hasError` state to `false` ?

Comment: When I get the time, I'll create a full solution on codepen.